# How check if a string is surrounded by brackets?

Tags: jquery

In my spring project, I have a dashboard page where some links should open in a popup windows, and some links shouldn't. Now, I have this code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: {
            effect: "fadeIn",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut",
            duration: 1000
          }
        });

    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != '<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout"/>') {
                var id_dialog_div = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
                var dialog_div = $('<div id="'+id_dialog_div+'" class="dialog" title="Basic dialog"> <p> <span id="text'+id_dialog_div+'"></span> </p> </div>');
                $("#container").append(dialog_div);
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
                    var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                    $( dialog_div ).dialog({ title: $temp.find('title').text() });
                    $('#text'+id_dialog_div).html($temp.remove('head').html());
                    $( dialog_div ).dialog({ height: 720 });
                    $( dialog_div ).dialog({ width: 720 });
                    $( dialog_div ).dialog( "open" );
                });
        }
    });
});
```

I need modify this code to verify not only a specific page, but if the link is surrounnded by brackets, which will indicate the link should open in a popup windows.

Anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: FYI `$('document')` returns empty object. You are lucky jQuery handles ready pseudo event with a promise but it should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try and find them using the ascii characters for "(" and ")" which are 40 and 41.
I don't know what the syntax would be (I program in java not jquery) so this is written in pseudocode, but you could try something like this:

```
String string_link = "link"

If ascii(character 1 of string_link) = 40 && 
ascii(last character of string_link) = 41 then boolean popup = true
```

I know this probably isn't the answer you were looking for but hopefully it will help